# Extended display for two monitors

Tags: windows-7, display, remote-desktop

I have three monitors connected to a windows 7 machine. I would like to extend the monitor from far left to the monitor in far right. And keep the middle screen independent. 
Is there anyway to do this? I have two graphics cards.All NEC monitors connected with DVI cables. The middle screen directly connected to one of the graphics card, and other two screens are connected using a dvi split cable. The main reason i want to do this is to share the left most and right most screen for a remote desktop and and the middle screen for another remote desktop session. The middle screen is connected to AMD Radeon 6320 and the dvi splitter is connected to AMD Firepro 2270

Comment: by independent you mean what? and kind of video card do you have.

Comment: Along with above comment what type of monitors and connectors do you have?

Answer (score 0):

Just connect left and right monitor seperetaly (with seperate cable) to your graphic card (as long as it has 2x DVI outputs or 1x DVI and 1x HDMI or DP (u can convert with adapter from them)).

If I'm not mistaken (correct me if I am), you are using split cable, that is from one DVI port in graphic card you connect two monitors?
If that's the case, then you can't have two seperate displays (neither you can't extend left monitor to right monitor) because you have one signal output.
Reason is simple: computer does not recognise two monitors, but only one.

Also, please provide model of the GPU that will be in charge of managing two monitors.
Model of each monitor would be helpful too.